# Find a word using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract ads that contain two special Persian words "توافق" or "توافقی" from a website. I am using BeautifulSoup and split the content in the soup to find the ads that have my special words, but my code does not work, May you please help me?
Here is my simple code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://divar.ir/s/tehran")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "kt-post-card__body"})
for content in results:
    words = content.split()
    if words == "توافقی" or words == "توافق":
        print(content)
```

Comment: You are splitting the content into words, so `words` is a list of strings, not a string.  You can't compare a list to a string.  What you want is `if 'توافقی' in words or 'توافق' in words:`

Comment: @Tim Roberts, when I split the content into words I get this error: "object is not callable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that `توافقی` is appeared in the div tags with `kt-post-card__description` class, I will use this. Then you can get the adds by using tag's properties like `.previous_sibling` or `.parent` or whatever...

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://divar.ir/s/tehran")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "kt-post-card__description"})
for content in results:
    text = content.text
    if "توافقی" in text or "توافق" in text:
        print(content.previous_sibling)   # It's the h2 title.
```

Comment: this code shows a few ads. I think there are many ads that contain توافقی.May I know your idea?

Comment: @Ali It shows few ads because they are what being fetched by your request(you get the html of the requested page only). The other ads are dynamically fetched using AJAX requests for example after scrolling the page.

Answer (score 2):

There are differnet issues first one, also mentioned by @Tim Roberts, you have to compare the list items with in:

```
if 'توافقی' in words or 'توافق' in words:
```

Second you have to seperate the texts from each of the child elements, so use `get_text()` with separator:

```
words=content.get_text(' ', strip=True)
```

**Note:** *`requests` do not render dynamic content, it justs focus on static one*

###### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://divar.ir/s/tehran')
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
results=soup.find_all('div',attrs={'class':"kt-post-card__body"})
for content in results:
    words=content.get_text(' ', strip=True)
    if 'توافقی' in words or 'توافق' in words:
        print(content.text)
```

---

An alternative in this specific case could be the use of `css selectors`, so you could select the whole `<article>` and pick elements you need:

```
results = soup.select('article:-soup-contains("توافقی"),article:-soup-contains("توافق")')

for item in results:
    print(item.h2)
    print(item.span)
```

Answer (score 1):

so basically you are trying to split bs4 class and hence its giving error. Before splitting it, you need to convert it into text string.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get("https://divar.ir/s/tehran")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

results = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "kt-post-card__description"})
for content in results:
    words = content.text.split()
    if "توافقی" in words or "توافق" in words:
        print(content)
```

Comment: `if "توافقی" or "توافق" in words:` This condition is always evaluated to True because of the first condition. So it doesn't work.

Comment: it totally depends on your requirement. in your initial code, you added 'or' condtion hence i've added or condtion. Please explain your condition requirements

Comment: The body of `if "توافقی" or "توافق" in words:` condition is always executed ! It doesn't depend on anything. Any non-empty string is truthy in Python.